# encode string that contains ASCII in objective c

Tags: objective-c

This seems to be an easy one, but I really can't find an answer. I found how to convert a single ascii `char` to `String`, but how can I convert a string that already contains ascii char to a normal string? For example, the string is `5 &#43; 2 &#61; 7` where `&#43;` is `+` and `&#61;` is `=`. The expected outcome would be `5 + 2 = 7`. How can that be done in objective c?